# Where do you store shared secrets used in building VMs dynamically (phoenix servers)?

Tags: virtual-machines, configuration-management, password-management

We use vagrant to spin up linux VMs for dev, testing, and evaluation servers for our software.  Most often, devs are using linux from VMs inside an AD-connected windows7 box.

The configuration of the servers happens through puppet manifests. Our environment contains both linux and windows, and we rely on AD for access control to most things.

In our environment, we use client-side x509 certificates to access web services all over the organization.

We want our developers and testers to be able to spin up VMs at their leisure. In some instances, those VMs will need some secrets to function properly.

Therefore, We want to store the secrets centrally and automate the insertion of said secrets (client certificates, and passwords where unavoidable) into the vagrant build process, but we are looking for a secure centralized repository to store the secrets. We know how to get the secrets into vagrant and the VMs, but we're not finding a lot of pre-packaged solutions for the centralized password store.

We've looked at using Active Directory to store the secrets, but this will require some custom development. It looks like I cannot create an LSA-Secret object using the admin tools, but will have to do so through code.

We've looked at things like Password manager Pro and Secret Server, but the price is prohibitive.

http://www.thycotic.com/products_secretserver_overview.html
http://www.manageengine.com/products/passwordmanagerpro/

Where do you store secrets when automatically building servers? Has anyone used a 3rd party product like this with any success?

Thanks

-Jimmy

Comment: I had a customer with this issue and I resorted to suggesting secret server. Other thing that I have heard good of is Zoho, but I haven't used it though. Have you looked into some open source tools? Also, I upvoted and starred this since I am interested in this.